# Build dynamic T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a question regarding SQL with MS SQL Server

I have a table as such

```
customer
id  country_id post_code_id
1      AU          1
2      GB          1
```

I have postcode tables seperated as such

```
post_codes_AU
post_codes_GB
etc..
```

Is there a way I can use country_id in the query to join the right table.. e.g.,

```
select * from customer c
inner join post_codes_ '+c.country_id+' as pc on pc.id=c.post_code_id
```

Comment: If you combine all your post_codes into a single table separated by a country_id (or ISO code), this problem becomes a trivial join. Your design is a good example of a schema that has created difficult problems down the road because of lack of normalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can not join the query like this.

To make a proper query you can do one of the following:

- Make a partitioned view over the post_codes_... tables and join this view
- Generate the queries for each country_id in the customer table and glue them together with `UNION ALL` statements.

Comment: For the first option I would also recommend to create a stored procedure that would sort of refresh the view (on demand or by some schedule), building the `drop view/create view` script dynamically and executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put `[]` around the table name if it really has a space in the name as your sample query suggests.  This looks like a typo so you might not need to do that.  Once you do that it should work fine as dynamic SQL.

Be sure that you are aware of potential pifalls of using dynamic SQL before you go that route though.  This is worth a read:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and join that;

```
-- #1 create a view . . . .
create view MyPostCodes

as

select
    country_id='AU',
    post_code_id
from
    post_codes_AU
union
select
    country_id='GB',
    post_code_id
from
    post_codes_GB
go
-- #2 now join like this
select * from customer c
inner join MyPostCodes as pc on pc.id=c.post_code_id and pc.country_id=c.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your query will work, changed a little.

```
Select * from customer c 
Inner Join post_codes
On concat('post_codes_',c.country_id)=Post_codes.post_code_id
```

Or have a try with below piece of code,

```
 Select * from customer c
 Inner Join post_codes 
 On right(1-charindex('_',reverse(post_codes_id)),post_codes_id) =c.country_id
```

Before comparing remove the exact code to compare to.